# Etsy API call for standard search

Tags: api, search, etsy

What is the `Esty` api call for the standard search on [etsy.com](https://www.etsy.com/)?
I would like to get the number of results when searching for "winter giraffe" on `etsy.com`, which is 472.

So far, I have:

```
String api_key = ...;
String terms = "winter+giraffe";

try{

        String output = getHTML("https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/listings/active.js?keywords="+
                       terms+"&limit=12&includes=Images:1&api_key="+api_key);
        String input = output;
        int index = input.indexOf("listing_id");
        int count = 0;
        while (index != -1) {
                count++;
                input = input.substring(index + 1);
                index = input.indexOf("listing_id");
        }
        System.out.println("\nNo of listings is : " + count);


       }
       catch(Exception e){System.out.println("Something went wrong.");}
```

The problem is that this gives me

> "No of listings is :24"

Also, in the output string, it says :

> "count":50100. So that is also not it..

Answer (score 0):

It isn't obvious to me what the keywords parameter value is checked against.
You might have better luck using **tags** instead of **keywords**:

```
String output = getHTML("https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/listings/active.js?tags="+terms+"&limit=12&includes=Images:1&api_key="+api_key);
```

(I get 7 results with this query.)